# How to change the colormap in QGIS 2.01?

Tags: qgis, symbology, color-ramp

I decided to say goodbye to ArcGIS and switch to QGIS which is nice, but it has given me a hard time to handle various problems. 
Few months ago, I made a map using QGIS 1.8 with a relief background having a colormap from green to brown. Later on, I upgraded to QGIS to 2.01. Now, when I reopen the same map project with the intent to change the colormap of the map because that one was very pale. But, it seems that either I forgot how a colormap can be changed or my QGIS has lost that capability or there is a problem with my tif file which has three bands.

This is what I get when I open the Colormap tab in the Layer Properties window:

[image: Almost everything is frozen and I don't know why]

Any idea of how I can change the colormap?

Answer (score 5):

The colour map is all done in the style tab in 2.0

[image]